# Silverlight doens't show Xaml

Tags: xaml, silverlight

So I try to generate the xaml code below with visual studios, Silverlight.
But when I put parts into comment to check where my fault is, it never works.
So I would like to find out where my fault is so I can try to interact with Javascript

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" ShowGridLines="True" Loaded="onLoaded">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Canvas Height="300" Width="600">
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="61.57098099504444" Height="160.95803800991115" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="0.0" Y1="157.95" X2="45.0" Y2="157.95" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Bottom="112.86424230466895" Height="153.59151539066212" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="75.0" Y1="110.34" X2="120.0" Y2="110.34" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Bottom="54.47593841460492" Height="120.54812317079018" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="150.0" Y1="185.25" X2="195.0" Y2="185.25" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="225" Canvas.Bottom="178.28025619556524" Height="95.23948760886945" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="225.0" Y1="74.10000000000002" X2="270.0" Y2="74.10000000000002" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Bottom="60.658737319718924" Height="82.68252536056214" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="300.0" Y1="198.0" X2="345.0" Y2="198.0" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="375" Canvas.Bottom="176.2529831230876" Height="52.79403375382487" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="375.0" Y1="97.34999999999997" X2="420.0" Y2="97.34999999999997" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="450" Canvas.Bottom="66.47512033126283" Height="129.84975933747432" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="450.0" Y1="168.6" X2="495.0" Y2="168.6" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="525" Canvas.Bottom="31.87007514135977" Height="145.05984971728049" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="525.0" Y1="195.6" X2="570.0" Y2="195.6" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="600" Canvas.Bottom="93.02414165274203" Height="156.551716694516" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="600.0" Y1="128.7" X2="645.0" Y2="128.7" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="675" Canvas.Bottom="106.2876271364089" Height="30.724745727182178" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
      <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" X1="675.0" Y1="178.35000000000002" X2="720.0" Y2="178.35000000000002" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="148.5" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="276.6" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Green" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="183.0" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Yellow" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="225" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="142.5" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="121.5" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="375" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="237.0" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Green" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="450" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="141.0" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="525" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="100.5" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="600" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="207.0" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Green" />
      <Rectangle Width="45" Canvas.Left="675" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="124.50000000000001" Opacity="0.5" Fill="red" />
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="3" X1="-50.0" Y1="0.0" X2="750.0" Y2="0.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="-50">0</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="30.0" X2="750.0" Y2="30.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="30" Canvas.Left="-50">2</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="60.0" X2="750.0" Y2="60.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="60" Canvas.Left="-50">4</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="90.0" X2="750.0" Y2="90.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="90" Canvas.Left="-50">6</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="120.0" X2="750.0" Y2="120.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="120" Canvas.Left="-50">8</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="3" X1="-50.0" Y1="150.0" X2="750.0" Y2="150.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="150" Canvas.Left="-50">10</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="180.0" X2="750.0" Y2="180.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="180" Canvas.Left="-50">12</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="210.0" X2="750.0" Y2="210.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="210" Canvas.Left="-50">14</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="240.0" X2="750.0" Y2="240.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="240" Canvas.Left="-50">16</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" X1="-50.0" Y1="270.0" X2="750.0" Y2="270.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="270" Canvas.Left="-50">18</TextBlock>
      <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="3" X1="-50.0" Y1="300.0" X2="750.0" Y2="300.0" Opacity="0.5" />
      <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="300" Canvas.Left="-50">20</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Bottom="106.25" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Computersystemen 1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="110" Canvas.Bottom="170.3" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Databanken 1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Bottom="123.5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Engels
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="260" Canvas.Bottom="103.25" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Frans
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="335" Canvas.Bottom="80" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Boekhoudkundig inzicht
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Bottom="150.5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Netwerken1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="485" Canvas.Bottom="102.5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Programmeren 1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="560" Canvas.Bottom="60" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Software engineering 1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="635" Canvas.Bottom="135.5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        User interfaces 1
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Canvas.Left="710" Canvas.Bottom="60" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="AUTO">
        Management accounting
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
 </Viewbox>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="180" Height="200" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20">Fred Sanchez</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Fred Sanchez
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Lois Weaver
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Denise Andrews
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Charles Butler
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Joan Willis
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Patrick Bailey
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Michael Elliott
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Wanda Bailey
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        Bonnie Collins
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock>
        John Black
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" MouseLeftButtonUp="onSagemClicked" Margin="1">
        Standaardafwijking en gemiddelde
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="1">
        Minimum en maximum
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So, I'm not quite sure what your question is exactly. However a couple things stand out. Like `TextBlock` doesn't support Background Property as it's a frameworkelement. So remove those and use the Border's they're embedded in instead. Second, that code could be reduced to less than half what it is currently. Let me know your actual question.

Comment: I have to do a project for school and i have to generate a barchart. But when   open it in Kaxaml or VisualStudios, it opens perfect but when i want to build it with ilverlight in internet explorer it doesn't show anything. so i wonder why it doens't show anything

Comment: Because for starters, your XAML is invalid for Silverlight for the first point I mention. You're also not doing your assignment correctly as you're not currently "generating" anything. You should probably instead just go grab a bar chart control like the free one available in the Silverlight Toolkit and populate it with data instead of trying to re-invent the wheel. :)